# "Чувак" - это смешное слово сказать?

Tags: жаргон

Сказал бы мужчина это другу-мужчине? Каковы хорошие альтернативы?

Я из США.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, мужчина может обратиться к другому мужчине-**другу** с помощью этого слова. Но оно не нейтральное и в определенном контексте может прозвучать пренебрежительно. К тому же нужно учитывать, что в нашу речь оно пришло из воровского (тюремного) жаргона. Но я думаю, что, если иностранец немного ошибется со стилистикой общения, ничего страшного не произойдет. Я бы умилилась. Кстати, имейте в виду, что женская версия этого слова — *чувиха* — считается грубой.

Comment: Она не считается грубой, а несёт негативный смысл.

Comment: Спасибо большой! Этот что я думал. )

Answer (score 2):

> **Чува́к** — жаргонный синоним слов «парень», «юноша», «мужчина». Возможно как обращение и как название вместо имени. Применимо к любому человеку мужского пола. Имеет арготическую окраску.
> (...)
> Среди стиляг (то есть в «прозападно настроенной молодёжной среде» 1950-х — 1960-х годов) «расшифровка» этого слова была такова: «человек, уважающий высокую американскую культуру».
>
> https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA

Насчёт того, что «в нашу речь оно пришло из воровского (тюремного) жаргона»: на самом деле это слово происходит от цыганского слово *чаво* — «парень». Но да: в воровском (не «тюремном»!) жаргоне XIX и начала XX веков много слов заимствовано из цыганского языка. И да: слово «чувиха», засвидетельствованное ещё в начале XX века, в воровском жаргоне означало «подруга вора», а иногда даже «проститутка». Так что с женским вариантом этого слова лучше поосторожнее!

Да: там ещё был вопрос про альтернативы; я согласен, что самые модные сейчас синонимы соответствующего стилистического ряда — «братан» и «бро», и я бы ещё добавил «брателлу». Ещё можно использовать слова «пацан» и «хлопец».

Comment: Егор, Википедия — общедоступный ресурс, ее пока не закрыли. Учитывая, что вопрос задан иностранцем, я постаралась ответить так, чтобы было понятно в случае автоматического перевода, отсюда пояснение про тюремный. Воровской и тюремный жаргон часто пересекаются.

Comment: «Википедия — общедоступный ресурс, ее пока не закрыли» — и что из этого сообщения должно следовать? «Я постаралась ответить так, чтобы было понятно в случае автоматического перевода, отсюда пояснение про тюремный» — хм! Никогда не думал, что автоматический перевод разбирается в тюремном жаргоне. Если так, это его украшает!

Comment: Про Википедию - это к тому, что автору вопроса очевидно нужен совет носителей языка, а не рассказ об этимологии, скопированный с Вики. Пояснение про тюремный жаргон я дала, потому что сегодня слова "вор" и "воровской" имеют более узкое значение, чем раньше. Говоря "воровской жаргон", мы понимаем, что речь идет не только о тех, кто крадет, а в целом о преступном мире. Иностранцу это может быть непонятно, поэтому я дала пояснение.

Comment: «автору вопроса очевидно нужен совет носителей языка, а не рассказ об этимологии, скопированный с Вики» — автору вопроса нужна этимология а-ля Задорнов, скопированная с любительского сайта?))) Автор вам сам об этом сообщил?

Answer (score 1):

Это слово можно смело употреблять по отношению к третьему лицу, к другу — можно, но осторожно — с его согласия. Для дружеских отношений подходят *чувачок*, *старик*, *старина*, *мужик*, а также неполные имена или неполные фамилии, клички: *Бородин*/*Борода*, *Евламьпиев*/*Ева*.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, такое обращение уместно больше в молодежной среде.

Answer (score 0):

Жаргонное слово, которым обозначают представителей мужского пола. Обычно его используют коллеги, одноклассники, друзья примерно в возрасте от 10 до 25 лет. Наиболее близкие слова: ‟братан”, ‟бро”. Переводчики обычно переводят слово *dude* как ‟чувак”.